# How using entity framework fluent API to config such relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

1.A car may have one dealer if it is delivered out of the storage(the car belong to the dealer),otherwise,A car has no dealer.

2.A dealer may have a collection of cars or not.
The code is below

```
public Car
{
  public long Id {get;set;}
  public Dealer Dealer{get;set;}
}

public Dealer
{
  public long Id{get;set;}
  public ICollection<Car> Cars {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasOptional(m => m.Dealer)
            .WithMany(m => m.Cars);
```